# Finding the centroid of the area between two curves

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When I have an area bounded by curves, is there a built-in way to find the center of the area? Or do I have to plot it first and then use `ComponentMeasurements` on it?

For example: the area under $y= 1-x^2/4$ and above the $x$ axis:

[image: my region]

Comment: The centroid is given by $\bar x = (1/A) \iint x \; dA$, $\bar y = (1/A) \iint y \; dA$, where $A=\iint \; dA$ and the integrals are over the area.  Does that answer your question, or is it about how to set up such integrals in *Mathematica*?

Comment: I know how to calculate it with integrals, I want to know if there is a function to do it directly (without me having to calculate $dA$, $X_e$, $Y_e$ first)

Comment: then you´ll have to specify more precisely what your input looks like

Comment: @YvesKlett My input looks like I wrote above: A number of curves which enclose an area

Comment: So you want to work with the (rasterized?) graphics expression and no additional information?

Comment: @YvesKlett `the area under y=1−x^2/4 and above the x axis` is enough information to solve it by hand, why should it be insufficient here?

Comment: If you want to do it algebraically, @MichaelE2 and @Artes solutions stand. But you mentioned `ComponentMeasurements`, which primarily works on rasterized graphics. You could also use the resulting vector graphics for a discrete center of gravity approach... but your question does not specify what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @YvesKlett I thought it was clear enough... His question basically is: "Is there a built in that takes a curve (or a set of curves) and finds the centroid of the enclosing area using calculus or should I plot it, rasterize it and use `ComponentsMeasurements`". Looks like they already know what `Comp..M...` does

Comment: @Hypnotoad then the first OP comment in combination with `C..P..M` threw me off. Sounded like the OP knew his way around the calculus part.

Comment: @YvesKlett I did some research before posting and all results I got involved finding the centroid using that function; so I asked here if that's the only way to do it (apart from building the integrals by hand and evaluating them)

Comment: what is insuffieient is we don know how general the curves can be. Always monotonic functions of x with exactly two intersection points? Points guaranteed obtainable in closed form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is inelegant for the specific example, but may be useful for more general cases:

```
boolf[x_, y_] := (y > 0 && y < 1 - x^2/4);
area = NIntegrate[If[  boolf[x, y] , 1, 0], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}]
    -> 2.66667
cx = NIntegrate[If[  boolf[x, y] , x, 0], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}]/ area
    -> ~10^-16
cy = NIntegrate[If[  boolf[x, y] , y, 0], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}]/area
    -> 0.4
```

The exact results for the example are by the way:

```
area = Integrate[( 1 - x^2/4 ) , {x, -2, 2}]  -> 8/3
cy = Integrate[( 1 - x^2/4 )/2  ( 1 - x^2/4 ) , {x, -2, 2}] / area  -> 2/5
cx = Integrate[ x  ( 1 - x^2/4 ) , {x, -2, 2}] / area   -> 0
```

Edit:
Further explanation: we construct a logical function of x,y which is `True` inside your region and `False` otherwise, then perform area integrals over the entire plane using the definitions of area and centroid, and relying on the integrands to be zero outside the region of interest.

As noted by Daniel in a comment that seems to have disappeared(?) you can use the analytic `Integrate` function over the entire plane (`±∞`):

```
fa[x_,y_]:= If[(y > 0 &&  y < 1 - x^2/4), 1, 0];
area = Integrate[fa[x, y], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]
    -> 8/3
cx = Integrate[ x fa[x,y], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]/ area
    -> 0
cy = Integrate[ y fa[x,y], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]/area
    -> 2/5
```

This does need a bit of warning, `Integrate[]` fails for even slightly more complicated expressions, so `NIntegrate[]` is a bit safer (though it yields a numerical approximation).

Comment: oops worked on that before i saw Danial's note. And it does indeed work with plain Integrate (which surprised me..)

Comment: Thanks, But could u explain what exactly you did ? (I'm new to Mathematica)

Comment: @a3f: What is it you still don't understand?

Comment: The code is a perhaps more transparent if you use the built-in function `Boole`, which already returns values of 1 (when its argument evalutaes to `True` and 0 otherwise). Thus: `indicator[x_, y_] := Boole[y > 0 && y < 1 - x^2/4]` . And then `area = Integrate[indicator[x, y], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}]`, `cx = Integrate[x indicator[x, y], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}]/area`, etc.

Comment: As you know bounds on the region, you might as well use them, i.e., integrate just for `{x, -2, 2}` and `{y, 0, 1}`. Especially in case you integrate numerically.

Comment: @murray Ah I got it now. I thought the `If` would cause the `Integrate` to take a Boolean as first argument, didn't think of it as a function

Comment: The disappeared comment was on a response that was deleted by its author.

Answer (score 14):

### Edit: Preface

After being on this site for a few months, I've learned quite a bit about what *Mathematica* can do quickly.  Below I've revised my code to take advantage of built-in vectorized functions.  One could compile the functions as well, but the advantages perhaps outweigh the disadvantages.  The increase in speed is slight on approximate real numbers (because the number crunching is done in a very few function calls and so is already "mostly compiled" anyway); however, the first function `centroid1` is exact on polygons, and a compiled function would not return an exact result on exact input.  I added a new one that implements a Simpson's Rule type integration that is exact on figures whose boundary can be parametrized by quadratic polynomials.  I also updated the timings, since I have a new machine.

### Revised original method

Originally I had done this for someone who had wanted to find centroids of polygons, for which `NIntegrate` seemed too slow.  I thought it was pretty cool at the time and wanted to share it.  I guess it's pretty clear that the simple answer to the original question of @a3f is that there is no built-in centroid function.

The code below replaces the previous code but is based on the same mathematical ideas as before.  The line integrals around the boundary,
$$A={1\over2} \int x\;dy - y\;dx, \quad M_x=-\int x\,y\;dx, \quad M_y=\int x\,y\;dy\,,$
which by Green's Theorem represent the area, `x` moment, and `y` moment respectively, are approximated using a linear interpolation of the boundary at sample points.

```
area1[pts_] := Module[{x, y}, {x=#[[1]],y=#[[2]]} &@ Transpose @ pts;
   Total[x RotateLeft[y] - RotateLeft[x] y]] / 2;
xMoment1[pts_] := Module[{x, y}, {x=#[[1]],y=#[[2]]} &@ Transpose @ pts; 
   Total[(x - RotateLeft[x]) (2 x y + y RotateLeft[x] + 
        x RotateLeft[y] + 2 RotateLeft[x] RotateLeft[y])]] / 6;
yMoment1[pts_] := Module[{x, y}, {x=#[[1]],y=#[[2]]} &@ Transpose @ pts; 
   Total[(RotateLeft[y] - y) (2 x y + y RotateLeft[x] + 
        x RotateLeft[y] + 2 RotateLeft[x] RotateLeft[y])]] / 6;

centroid1[poly_Polygon] := centroid1[First[poly]];
centroid1[poly_List?(Depth[#] == 4 &)] := (* multiple-polygon figure (e.g. Italy) *)
   {#[[1]], #[[2]]} / #[[3]] &[ 
        # . Sign@Last[#] & @ {xMoment1 /@ #, yMoment1 /@ #, area1 /@ #} & @ poly];
centroid1[poly_List?(Depth[#] == 3 &)] := {xMoment1[#], yMoment1[#]} / area1[#] & @ poly;
```

### Polygons

As a test I loaded Italy and found its centroid:

```
itPoly = CountryData["Italy", "Polygon"];
centroid1[itPoly]
(* {12.0822, 42.7896} *)
```

It's the centroid of a "flat-earth" Italy, since no adjustment for spherical coordinates is made.

```
Graphics[{itPoly, PointSize[Large], Red, Point[centroid1[itPoly]]}]
```

[image: Centroid of Italy]

The new code is faster:

```
centroid1[itPoly] // AbsoluteTiming (* new *)
(* {0.000468, {12.0822, 42.7896}} *)

oldCentroid[itPoly] // AbsoluteTiming (* old *)
(* {0.007083, {12.0822, 42.7896}} *)
```

The function `centroid1` is faster than `NIntegrate` on polygons:

```
{#[[1]], #[[2]]}/#[[3]] &@(Plus @@ (Module[{X, Y, a, xm, ym},
        X = Interpolation[Append[#, First[#]] &[First /@ #], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
        Y = Interpolation[Append[#, First[#]] &[Last /@ #], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
        a = NIntegrate[X[t] Y'[t], {t, 1, 1 + Length[#]}];
        xm = NIntegrate[-X[t] Y[t] X'[t], {t, 1, 1 + Length[#]}];
        ym = NIntegrate[X[t] Y[t] Y'[t], {t, 1, 1 + Length[#]}];
        {xm, ym, a}
        ] & /@ First[itPoly])) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.616189, {12.0822, 42.7896}} *)
```

### Curves

The function `centroid1` above is not exact on curves, but it may be accurate enough for some work. In most cases, `NIntegrate` is hard to beat it for accuracy.  To apply `centroid1`, first you have to convert the curve to an approximate polygon (pick sample points).

#### Graphs

For the example proposed by @a3f, we can extract the plotted points of the graph with `Cases`.  Since the base is straight, they form the polygon and we can apply `centroid1`:

```
(paraPoly = Transpose@{#, 1 - #^2/4} &@Range[-2., 2, 4/1000];
 centroid1[paraPoly]) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000356, {6.83717*10^-17, 0.4}} *)
```

The error in the y-coordinate is less than $10^{-6}$.

```
Graphics[{Polygon[paraPoly], PointSize[Large], Red, 
  Point[centroid1[paraPoly]]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Centroid of parabolic segment]

If we compare with `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` as @murray, @george2079 have answered, we get:

```
(a = Integrate[(1 - x^2/4), {x, -2, 2}];
  xm = Integrate[x (1 - x^2/4), {x, -2, 2}];
  ym = Integrate[(1 - x^2/4)/2 (1 - x^2/4), {x, -2, 2}];
  {xm, ym} / a) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.020392, {0, 2/5}} *)

(a = NIntegrate[(1 - x^2/4), {x, -2, 2}];
  xm = NIntegrate[x (1 - x^2/4), {x, -2, 2}];
  ym = NIntegrate[(1 - x^2/4)/2 (1 - x^2/4), {x, -2, 2}];
  {xm, ym} / a) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.013740, {0., 0.4}} *)
```

The first is exact and the second is accurate to `$MachinePrecision`.

#### Parametric Curves

I made up, at random, simple closed curve (picture down below),

```
f[t_] := {Cos[2 \[Pi] t] (2 + Cos[2 \[Pi] t] + Sin[8 \[Pi] t]), Sin[2 \[Pi] t] (2 + Cos[2 \[Pi] t] + Sin[8 \[Pi] t])};
```

and found that for 200000  points, the `centroid1` calculation took about as long as the `NIntegrate`.  So we can compare the results.

```
(polarPoly = Transpose @ f[Range[0., 1, 1/200000]];
   centroid1[polarPoly]) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.104392, {0.95, -1.38784*10^-14}} *)

Module[{a, xm, ym},
  a = NIntegrate[Evaluate[f[t][[1]] f'[t][[2]]], {t, 0, 1}];
  xm = NIntegrate[Evaluate[-f[t][[1]] f[t][[2]] f'[t][[1]]], {t, 0, 1}];
  ym = NIntegrate[Evaluate[f[t][[1]] f[t][[2]] f'[t][[2]]], {t, 0, 1}];
  {xm, ym}/a
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.108268, {0.95, -1.11203*10^-16}} *)

Module[{a, xm, ym},
  a = Integrate[Evaluate[f[t][[1]] f'[t][[2]]], {t, 0, 1}];
  xm = Integrate[-Evaluate[f[t][[1]] f[t][[2]] f'[t][[1]]], {t, 0, 1}];
  ym = Integrate[ Evaluate[f[t][[1]] f[t][[2]] f'[t][[2]]], {t, 0, 1}];
  {xm, ym}/a
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {7.968150, {19/20, 0}} *)
```

[image: Centroid of polar blotch]

The errors in the `x` coordinate are a little over `10^-10` and `10^-16` (or `$MachinePrecision`) for `centroid1` and `NIntegrate` respectively.  (But on 5000 points `centroid1` is 100 times faster and has an error in `x` of a little over `10^-7`, which is good enough for plotting.)

---

### Addition -- Simpson's Rule

If we have an even number of points, we can use a method similar to Simpson's Rule.  Think of the points as alternating between "endpoints" and "midpoints," and then use quadratic interpolation to approximate the boundary of the region.  This tends to be better on curved boundaries and worse on straight boundaries such as polygons.  With polygons, we will get an inaccurate result unless we bisect the segments; so from the points of view of both accuracy and speed, it loses over the linear method of `centroid1`.

```
With[{
    areaFn = Total[(-3 #1 - 4 #2 + #3) #4 + 4 (#1 - #3) #5 - (#1 - 4 #2 - 3 #3) #6]/6 &,
    momentFn = Total[(-10 #1 - 6 #2 + #3) #4^2 + (6 #1 - 8 #2 + 2 #3) (#4 #5) + 
       8 (#1 - #3) #5^2 + (-#1 + #3) (#4 #6) + (-2 #1 + 8 #2 - 6 #3) (#5 #6) +
       (-#1 + 6 #2 + 10 #3) #6^2]/30 &},
 area2[pts_] := Module[{x, y}, {x=#[[1]],y=#[[2]]} &@ Transpose @ pts;
   areaFn[x[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]], x[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]], 
     RotateLeft[x[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]], y[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]], 
     y[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]], RotateLeft[y[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]]]
   ];
 yMoment2[pts_] := Module[{x, y}, {x=#[[1]],y=#[[2]]} &@ Transpose @ pts;
   momentFn[x[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]], x[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]], 
     RotateLeft[x[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]], y[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]], 
     y[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]], RotateLeft[y[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]]]
   ];
 xMoment2[pts_] := Module[{x, y}, {x=#[[1]],y=#[[2]]} &@ Transpose @ pts;
   -momentFn[y[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]], y[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]], 
      RotateLeft[y[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]], x[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]], 
      x[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]], RotateLeft[x[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]]]
   ]
 ];

centroid2[poly_Polygon] := centroid2[First[poly]];
centroid2[poly_List?(Depth[#] == 4 &)] /; And @@ (EvenQ /@ Length /@ poly) :=
  {#[[1]], #[[2]]} / #[[3]] &[#.(Sign@Last[#]) &[
      {xMoment2 /@ #, yMoment2 /@ #, area2 /@ #} &@ poly]];
centroid2[poly_List?(Depth[#] == 3 &)] /; EvenQ @ Length[poly] :=
  {xMoment2[#], yMoment2[#]} / area2[#] &@ poly;
```

It's exact on regions with boundaries that have quadratic parametrizations.  Here care is taken to have the bottom segment bisected by the origin as midpoint in order to get the exact answer.

```
(paraPoly = Transpose@{#, 1 - #^2/4} &@ Range[-2, 2, 4/4] ~Join~ {{0, 0}};
 centroid2[paraPoly]) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000289, {0, 2/5}} *)
```

On the parametric curve, with 1000 sample points, the error in `x` is a little over `10^-7`, the same as `centroid1` on 5000 points.

```
f[t_] := {Cos[2 \[Pi] t] (2 + Cos[2 \[Pi] t] + Sin[8 \[Pi] t]), 
          Sin[2 \[Pi] t] (2 + Cos[2 \[Pi] t] + Sin[8 \[Pi] t])};
(polarPoly = Transpose @ f[Range[0., 1, 1/999]];
 centroid2[polarPoly]) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000714, {0.95, 5.44169*10^-10}} *)
```

Comment: Pretty slick. Easy +1. (Even though you answered quite a while ago.)

Answer (score 9):

Now in **V10** we have `ImplicitRegion` and `RegionCentroid` to do this easily:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[y > 0 && y <= 1 - x^2/4, {x, y}];
```

Then:

```
RegionCentroid[reg]
```

> {0, 2/5}

Answer (score 6):

This is a nice application of [Stokes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem). In fact it could almost be a homework problem - I hope it isn't, so I'll give only the first steps:

Observe the following results:

```
Curl[{0, x^2/2, 0}, {x, y, z}]

(* ==> {0, 0, x} *)

Curl[{-y^2/2, 0, 0}, {x, y, z}]

(* ==> {0, 0, y} *)

Curl[{-y/2, x/2, 0}, {x, y, z}]

(* ==> {0, 0, 1} *)
```

Now think about the surface integrals involved in the calculation: one is simply the area, i.e. its integrand is `1`. Then there are also the integrands `x` and `y` for the Cartesian components of the centroid.

But since you're given the curves bounding the area, you would be better off writing the area integrations as line integrals along the bounding curves. This is where Stokes' theorem comes in, combined with the above results.

The rest should be left for you to complete. This method, once you've written it down, will have the added advantage that it can give you the centroid of the  projection of any *three-dimensional* curve onto the `xy` plane.

Comment: It's not exactly homework. I am solving some problems in the book and wondered how I could use Mathematica to check if I was right. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: The nice thing about using this theorem is that you end up having to do only *half as many integrals* as in the accepted answer... so it's worth reading about Stokes' theorem, too!

Comment: @a3f: Presumably, then, you're just studying centroids as an application of single-variable calculus; in that case, using curl and Stokes's Theorem is something you might want to save for the future, when you study multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more down-to-earth solution in Mathematica that's probably closer to your current level of mathematics study. Just directly use the usual *one*-dimensional integrals involved in finding plane area and centroids.

```
f[x_] := 1 - x^2/4
area = Integrate[f[x], {x, -2, 2}]
yMoment = Integrate[x f[x], {x, -2, 2}]
xMoment = Integrate[(1/2) f[x]^2, {x, -2, 2}]
centroid = {yMoment/area, xMoment/area}
```

Of course there's no real need to calculate the x-coordinate, since by symmetry it must be 0.

Comment: We already started multi-variable calculus but thanks for your example.

Answer (score 4):

I had previously used the following function as part of [designing this site's logo](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/395), but I suppose it would be useful to explicitly have it as an answer to this question:

```
PolygonCentroid[pts_?MatrixQ] := With[{dif = Map[Det, Partition[pts, 2, 1, {1, 1}]]}, 
           ListConvolve[{{1, 1}}, Transpose[pts], {-1, -1}].dif/(3 Total[dif])]
```

A test, using OP's example:

```
reg = First[Cases[Plot[1 - x^2/4, {x, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 95], Line[l_] :> l, ∞]];

PolygonCentroid[reg]
   {1.00974*10^-6, 0.399977}
```

Pretty close for government work, I think. I exploited `Plot[]`'s capabilities for adaptive sampling in this case to help compute a more accurate estimate for the centroid. You can tweak `PlotPoints -> 95` or other options as needed for refinement.