# How to calculate the area of a listplot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I need to calculate the area enclosed in a two-dimensional listplot and following an answer to a similar question I tried this way:

```
imgnorm = (mnorm = 
MorphologicalComponents[
 Erosion[Binarize[
   ListLinePlot[{list}, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> False]], 
  0.5]]) // Colorize

listareas = {area1 = 1/. ComponentMeasurements[{mnorm, imgnorm}, "Area"], area2 = 2/. ComponentMeasurements[{mnorm, imgnorm}, "Area"]}
```

It works fine, however it is not precise enough for what I need to do because part of the area is taken by the black line.

The list is quite big and the points don't form a polygon.

EDIT: Here is the plot:

[image: list plot]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show the list resoluted-down perhaps? And could you close it to form a polygon for any practical purpose? For we know how to compute the polygon area...

Comment: When you say it's not a polygon, do you mean the lines overlap?  Or that it is not closed?

Comment: It is closed but the lines overlap, it wouldn't be a problem to remove those points if I could do it automatically, I don't need to be that precise

Comment: [Related answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22543/how-do-i-obtain-the-enclosed-area-of-this-particular-parametric-plot/22587#22587) -- assumes no self-intersections.

Comment: [Another related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17170/245) - actually I'm now pretty sure that this is a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: There are intersections between lines in my plot so it is not a real poligon but they are really small, could this explain why @MichaelE2 's answer works fine? (I can tell it because I know approximately what the area should be)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason to create a plot at all. According to your example, you have a list that can be plotted with `ListLinePlot`. That means it can be interpolated by a piecewise linear function. Consequently, you only need to find that linear function and calculate its integral.

Here is an example:

```
list = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 250]];

Integrate[
 Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 1, 
  Length[list]}]
```

This assumed that the `x` axis runs from `1` to the length of the `list`. It's easy to extend this to cases where the scale is different, or the `x` axis values are not evenly spaced.

The important ingredient is `InterpolationOrder`. The setting `1` leads to a linear interpolation the way it is plotted in `ListLinePlot`. Higher settings would produce smoothed approximations that may or may not be a better representation of the data you're trying to integrate.

Comment: I can't use an interpolating function because it is a cicle and some x values have more than one correspondant y value

Comment: I see. But then it will still be possible to divide your list into separate parts that *can* be considered functions over an interval on the horizontal axis. I'd say that's much more efficient than to try and extract the same information from a **plot** of any kind. Plotting is just a detour if you already have the data.