# Region bounded by Ellipse and Line

Tags: regions, geometry

I have an ellipse defined either as algebraic or geometric:

algebraic: `ax^2 + bxy +cy^2 + dx +ey +f = 0`

geometric: major Axis, minor Axis, x center, y center, rotation angle from horizontal

And I have a line that could be defined by two points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`

These two objects would intersect each other:

[image]

### Question

> How could I model the two objects, so that:
>
> For an ELLIPSE, I could get -
>
> 1) Length of the line within the ellipse
>
> 2) Area of the yellow shaded region (i.e. smaller area)

### Attempt

Previously I was able to get the area for a rotated ellipsoid under a horizontal plane. But now I would like to arbitrarily model that line (instead of a plane).

Thanks for your help!

Regards
Caid

***UPDATE:**

For a 3D ellipsoid:

`Nvolume[p_, abc_] :=

I was able to obtain the volume bounded under a plane defined as: `p = {Sin[k Degree], 0, Cos[k Degree]};`

And then, the planar area:

Unfortunately, that's about what I have. I need to convert the plane into a line for a 2D case.

Also if possible, I would like to obtain general equations for both.

Comment: This sounds like a question for math.stackexchange.com. Voting to migrate.

Comment: hmm actually i would like to model this in Mathematica

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you can show code it is more likely that people can show a solution.

Comment: Please add that bit of info to the question as well, then.

Comment: I have added the code which I was using previously, but only for the case of a 3D ellipsoid. Would like to be able to model a 2D case and obtain the general equations.

Comment: I don't think I have time to address this right now, but you may want to have a look at [Finding the centroid of the area between two curves](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17170/245). It's not directly a duplicate, but I bet one of the methods there can be applied to your problem. In particular, using Stokes' theorem (my answer) you can probably get analytical results. Just keep the orientation of the ellipse fixed and vary only the line (to reduce redundant parameters).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest to use the parametric form of a centered, rotated ellipse

```
{a Cos[t] Cos[Theta] - b Sin[t] Sin[Theta], a Cos[t] Sin[Theta] + b Sin[t] Cos[Theta]}
```

with a,b as the semimajor and semiminor axis, Theta as the rotation angle of the ellipse (0 for an axis oriented ellipse).

The trick is to rotate and center your problem into a configuration where your ellipse is centered and your line is horizontal.

If you want your ellipse in centered orientation, then you need to rotate the line about this center and use its parametric version first translated by {-xe,-ye} and then rotated by phi which is (refer to [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332105/how-to-apply-transformations-to-line-equation)):

```
{u Cos[phi]+v Sin[phi]-xe,−u Sin[phi]+v Cos[phi]-ye}
```

Entering this into the original line equation y=k x + d, solving for y and using the rotation angle -ArcTan[k] yields a horizontal line

```
Solve[k (u Cos[t] + v Sin[t] - xe) + d - ye == -u Sin[t] + 
  v Cos[t], v][[1, 1]] /. {u -> x, v -> y, t -> -ArcTan[k]} // Simplify
```

with

```
yl=(d - k xe - ye)/Sqrt[1 + k^2]
```

as the y-coordinate independent of x as expected.

The rotation angle is simply the negative of your angle phi between your line and the x-axis which is

```
phi=ArcTan[x2 - x1, y2 - y1]=ArcTan[k]
```

thus yielding the new parametric form of the Ellipse as

```
{a Cos[t] Cos[Theta-phi] - b Sin[t] Sin[Theta-phi], 
 a Cos[t] Sin[Theta-phi] + b Sin[t] Cos[Theta-phi]}
```

The intersection points are easy. They can be calculated from the transformed parametric form of the Ellipse with parameters t1 and t2 and then the differences between their x-coordinates is the length of the line L.

Now we have everything to calculate the area of the shaded region as the integral of the radius vector of the ellipse r=Sqrt[x^2+y^2] along the parameter interval {t1,t2} minus the area of the triangle (0 t1 t2) which is yl L / 2. The interval {t1,t2} is determined by the condition that the y-coordinate of the parametric ellipse equation must be equal to yl

```
Solve[a Cos[t] Sin[Theta-phi] + b Sin[t] Cos[Theta-phi] == yl, t] /. C[1] -> 0 // Simplify
```

The integral can be carried out analytically (it is actually an Elliptic integral)

```
 Integrate[ Sqrt[(a Cos[t] Cos[Theta-phi] - b Sin[t] Sin[Theta-phi])^2 + 
 (a Cos[t] Sin[Theta-phi] + b Sin[t] Cos[Theta-phi])^2] // Evaluate, {t, t1, t2}, 
 Assumptions -> {{a, b, t1, t2, Theta, phi} \[Element] Reals, t2 > t1,a>0,b>0}]
```

yielding the area

```
a (-EllipticE[t1, 1 - b^2/a^2] + EllipticE[t2, 1 - b^2/a^2]) -  yl L /2
```

which is independent of the rotation angle Theta.

Comment: thanks for your response. What do xe,ye,t1 and t2 refer to?

Comment: xe, ye are refering to the center of the ellipse (see text). t1 and t2 are the two solutions of the equation in the last solve statement in the text.

Comment: Am I right to assume that the analytical equation for the region shaded in yellow to be: `a (-EllipticE[t1, 1 - b^2/a^2] + EllipticE[t2, 1 - b^2/a^2]) -  yl L /2` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The first term is the integral solution and the second term is the area of the triangle (0 t1 t2).

Comment: @Corse, If my answer solves your problem please mark it as an answer.

Comment: so the only inputs i need to provide for your solution are: `a, b, theta, phi` How should I input the coordinates of the line? also, what is phi?

Comment: @Corse, the coordinates of the line enter as the parameters of the line equation k, d (line equation is y=k x + d, with two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) you can thus determine k and d). With k, d and the center of the ellipse (xe,ye) you can calculate yl (see above). phi is the rotation angle of the line to get horizontal (please read text above carefully!).

Comment: would it be possible to extend the solution to a 3D case? that is, to obtain a volume for an ellipsoid cut by a given plane ( thus extending the current case of obtaining area for an ellipse cut by a given line)

Comment: @Corse sure it would be possible... but harder do to ... I would try out a similar approach with an ellipsoid parametrized (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#Parameterization) in spherical coordinates (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates). Here please note that the u and v parameter are euqivalent to the polar and azimuthal angle respectively. Then rotate the system by the Euler angles (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) into a configuration where the plane is parallel with the e.g. x-y plane.

Comment: would using parametric equations for an ellipsoid be more straightforward to convert your solution to a 3D case?

Comment: @Corse, I suppose so, since you can take advantage of the identity of the parameters of the Ellipsoid (u,v) with the Euler Angles. Thus you again just get differences of angles in the arguments of the Ellipsoid equations instead of complex combinations of trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 4):

Rainer showed that we can use our calculus skills to set up the proper integral and evaluate it analytically.

But we can also solve this problem using the `Region` functionality in *Mathematica* to solve the problem.  Let's take an arbitrary ellipse and a couple of points, as stated in the OP

```
ellipse = TransformedRegion[
   Ellipsoid[{14, 14}, {5, 2}],
   RotationTransform[\[Pi]/3]
   ];
{p1, p2} = {{-2, 17}, {-8, 16}};
Graphics[{Red, ellipse, Black, Line@{p1, p2}, Green, PointSize[Large],
   Point@{p1, p2}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can find the length of the line inside the ellipse by

```
ArcLength@RegionIntersection[InfiniteLine[{p1, p2}], ellipse]
N@%
(* (40 Sqrt[259 (-6425 + 3828 Sqrt[3])])/(2881 - 252 Sqrt[3]) *)
(* 3.77312 *)
```

To get the area, we form a `HalfPlane` from the line, visualized below

```
Graphics[{Red, ellipse, Black, Opacity[0.5], 
  HalfPlane[{p1, p2}, {0, -1}]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
N@
 Area@RegionIntersection[HalfPlane[{p1, p2}, {0, -1}], ellipse]
(* 3.81495 *)
```

It's easy to verify that the sum of the areas found by using the two half planes from this line add up to the total area of the ellipse.