# Symbolic area calculation for a parametric self-intersecting closed curve

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, parametric-functions

The parametric equation of the curve is:

$$\begin{cases}
 x &= -9 \sin (2 t)-5 \sin (3 t) \\[6pt]
 y & = 9 \cos (2 t)-5 \cos (3 t)
\end{cases}\quad t\in[0,2\pi]$$

which can be easily visualized as:

[image]

The implicit form:

$$
\begin{array}{rl} 
F(x,y)=&625(x^2+y^2)^3-36450y(5x^4-10x^2y^2+y^4)\\
&+585816(x^2+y^2)^2-41620992(x^2+y^2)+550731776=0
\end{array}
$$
It is relatively easier to obtain the numerical solution of the enclosed area.

Is it possible to find the symbolic one? The key seems to be how to find the symbolic coordinates of the self-intersection points of the curve.

Comment: I think [How to get intersection values from a parametric graph](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph) is useful for you.

Comment: For my own part, I would be inclined to try it out, if I could copy-paste the formulas into *Mathematica*, but then I'm just a little bit lazy that way.

Comment: Closely related: [A: Finding the centroid of the area between two curves](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17170/245)

Comment: @MichaelE2  Try <code> ContourPlot[625x^6+1875x^4y^2+1875x^2y^4+625y^6-182250x^4y+364500x^2y^3-36450y^5+585816x^4+1171632x^2y^2+585816y^4-41620992x^2-41620992y^2+550731776==0,{x,-15,15},{y,-15,15}] </code>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although Belisarius' creative solution is entirely satisfactory, a solution symbolic at every step may be useful.  To begin, define

```
x[t_] := -9 Sin[2 t] - 5 Sin[3 t]
y[t_] :=  9 Cos[2 t] - 5 Cos[3 t]
```

and note that `t = π` corresponds to the uppermost point in the star in the question, `{0, 14}`}.  From there, the point `{0, -5}` can be reached by increasing or decreasing `t` by `2 π/5 + t0`, where `t0` is the change in `t` from the uppermost point to the nearest points at which two curve segments intersect.  This quantity is obtained by,

```
Solve[x[π + t] - x[π - t] == 0, t] /. C[1] -> 0;
t0 = %[[4, 1, 2]] - 2 π/5
(* (3 π)/5 + ArcTan[(2 Sqrt[15 (5 - 3/10 (9 - Sqrt[181]))])/(9 - Sqrt[181])] *)
```

(This simple derivation is based on the solution by Michael E2 to question [33947](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph), as highlighted by Shutao Tang in a comment above.)  Then, following Belisarius, we apply Green's Theorem.

```
5/2 Integrate[(y[t] D[x[t], t] - x[t] D[y[t], t]), {t, Pi + t0, Pi - t0}]
      // TrigExpand // FullSimplify
(* -(252/625) Sqrt[3 (-68561 + 5154 Sqrt[181])] + 261 π - 
       435 ArcCot[Sqrt[1/33 (-79 + 6 Sqrt[181])]] *)
```

The numerical value of this answer is `214.853`, as expected.

Comment: +1 clear, concise and provides the analytic expression :)

Comment: Such a result is what was really expected.

Comment: Sorry, just to understand your sayings: How comes my answer isn't _"a solution symbolic at every step"_ ?

Comment: @Belisarius  Certainly, I meant no criticism.  Your solution is creative and produces a quite satisfactory result.  I merely meant to convey that the approach I used did not require using `Root` functions at an intermediate point.  Would you like me to revise my first sentence?  Best wishes.

Comment: Ah,ok. Kind of a language barrier. Agree!

Answer (score 26):

The plan is first get the "external" contour and then use [Green's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensTheorem.html) to find its area.

```
r[t_] := {-9 Sin[2 t] - 5 Sin[3 t], 9 Cos[2 t] - 5 Cos[3 t], 0}

(*find the intersections*)
tr = Quiet@ToRules@Reduce[{r@t1 == r@t2, 0 < t1 < t2 < 2 Pi}, {t1, t2}];
pt = {t1, t2} /. {tr} // Flatten;
pts = SortBy[pt, N@# &];
pps = Partition[pts, 2];
```

Now we can use [Green's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensTheorem.html) to calculate the area by evaluating a line integral of a piecewise smooth function between those points. First we verify that the curve is oriented as expected:

```
Show[ParametricPlot[Most@r@t, {t, #[[1]], #[[2]]}, 
                    PlotRange -> {{-14, 14}, {-14, 14}}] & /@ pps] /. Line :> Arrow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So:

```
(*Green's theorem, "vectorial" form*)
k[{t2_, t1_}] = Integrate[Last@Cross[r@t, r'@t], {t, t1, t2}]/2;
arean = k /@ pps;
area = Total@arean;
arean // N
area // N
(* {42.9706, 42.9706, 42.9706, 42.9706, 42.9706} *)
(* 214.853 *)
```

So `area` is composed by five numerically equivalent integrals.
Let's get a symbolic form by using the first of them (the easier one to work with). You can verify that if we define:

```
ff[n_] := ArcTan[Sqrt@Root[1 - 2026 #1 + 67761 #1^2 - 2123042 #1^3 + 33867982 #1^4 - 
          251359006 #1^5 + 1020220287 #1^6 - 2365497302 #1^7 + 3139485186 #1^8 - 
          2365497302 #1^9 + 1020220287 #1^10 - 251359006 #1^11 + 33867982 #1^12 - 
          2123042 #1^13 + 67761 #1^14 - 2026 #1^15 + #1^16 &, n]];
```

then

```
 arean[[1]] == -((252*Sqrt[3*(-68561 + 5154*Sqrt[181])])/3125) - 174*(ff[1] - ff[2])
```

**which is one fifth of the symbolic result you're after.**

---

We may try to quickly verify if the result is reasonable by doing some image processing. We'll use a somewhat large image size (3000 pxs width) to get some accuracy:

```
lims = {-1, 1} + # &/@ N@Outer[#2[#1, t] &, Most@r@t, {MinValue, MaxValue}];

img = Show[ParametricPlot[a Most@r@t, {t, #[[1]], #[[2]]}, {a, 0, 1}, 
           PlotRange -> lims, Axes -> False, Mesh -> False, Frame -> False,
           ImageSize -> 3000] & /@ Partition[pts, 2]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now we count colored and white pixels

```
counts = Last /@ (ImageData[Binarize@img] // Flatten // Tally)
(* {6228712, 2366288} *)
```

And comparing the the area quotients calculated by both methods:

```
Times @@ (Subtract @@@ lims)/area // N
(* 3.64587 *)

Tr@counts/counts[[2]] // N
(* 3.63227 *)
```

we see that the results agree within reasonable limits

Comment: Exploiting the symmetry of the curve just might result in something simpler…

Comment: @J. M. I was doing that. Not very simple, though